# My python script suddenly stops

Tags: python, python-3.x

My python script suddenly stops when it executes a certain piece of code and before that it was working fine but now it like crashes when it executes it
Here is my code:

```py
import random; from time import sleep
while True:
    if 'playerName' in locals() or 'playerName' in globals():
        continue
    else:
        print('What is your name?')
        playerName = input()
    print(f'Hi there, {playerName}, welcome to this math game.')
    sleep(2)
    print('This game can make yourself custom equations to test your math. (only addition.)')
    sleep(2)
    print('Set the limit for numbers. (example. 1000 and 1234)')
    limit1 = int(input())
    limit2 = int(input())
    number1 = random.randint(limit1, limit2)
    number2 = random.randint(limit1, limit2)
    answer = number1 + number2
    print(f'Here is the question: {number1} + {number2}')
    sleep(1.5)
    print('Do you know the answer for this?')
    playerAnswer = input()
    if int(str(playerAnswer)) == answer:
        print(f'Good job, {playerName} You answered correctly!')
    elif int(str(playerAnswer)) != answer:
        print('Nope the answer is ' + str(int(answer)) + '.')
    print('Do you want to restart? (y/n)')
    restart = input()
    if restart == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print('Goodbye')
        break
```

It stops at the very end once it finishes one round. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Change the `continue` after `if 'playerName' in locals() or 'playerName' in globals():` to `pass`. You don't want to start a new loop iteration there, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if 'playerName' in locals() or 'playerName' in globals():
    continue
```

This statement will be only one executed after player will choose "Yes" and will not let you go to the next "print" statement, because 'playerName' will be always in locals() after first round of game.

Simple fix can look like that:

```
if not ('playerName' in locals() or 'playerName' in globals()):
    print('What is your name?')
    playerName = input()
```

Comment: But then it creates are error "unindent does not match any outer idendatation level"

Comment: This means that block of code is too much indented, please try to copy the code snippet from the answer and try again or unindent it in your piece of code.